# How to wrap multiple html tags at once in intellij idea

Tags: html, intellij-idea

I am learning HTML, and I'm trying to warp multiple tags at once in intellij idea. Any quick ways or shortcuts to do this. For example:

```html
<div>tag1</div>
<div>tag2</div>
<div>tag2</div>
```

I want to warp all these div tags with `<a>` tag, but I have to select them one by one and press `ctrl+alt+t` to add `<a>` tag, like this:

[image: img]

It causes much troubles, another example is:

```html
<div>tag1</div>
<a href="#">tag11</a>
<div>tag2</div>
<a href="#">tag22</a>
<div>tag2</div>
```

I am trying to encapsulate div tags with the `<a>` tag，and as I have been told, it is ineffective

Answer (score 1):

Structural Search & Replace may help here (`Edit | Search | Replace Structurally`).
Try a search template like this:

```
<div>$text$</div>
```

and a replace template like this:

```
<a><div>$text$</div></a>
```